# How to use COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have entered this in CMD

```
COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=9999 php composer.phar install
```

I think the above command will install Compser with the given timeout settings. However it gives error: 'COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Then I will run

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
```

Comment: At least we need to know which OS you execute your code on?

Comment: @mudasobwa, I use Windows 7.

Comment: `SET COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=9999` or smth like that. Google for `setting environment vars on Windows`. The CMD you were executing is for unix-like systems.

Answer (score 5):

In Windows you need to `set` the variable:

```
set "COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=9999" php composer.phar install
```

Enclosing in quotes is **required**.

Comment: It doesn't say anything. How can I check that the COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT is set to 9999?

Comment: You should be able to see the environment variables by using `set composer` or `set | more`